# Assigning a variable the file path from a user input Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, user-controls, user-input, filepath

I have a rather large script where I have set a few different files with direct paths. An example would be:

```
path1 = "C:/temp/"
path2 = "C:/users/<username>/My Documents/test.txt"
```

Essentially, I would like to set these variables to the file and/or folder path based on a user input. Is it possible to make the user browse to a location and then take that input path and place it into a variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`tkFileDialog`](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog) module has methods that allow the user to browse and select directories and files. Namely, `askdirectory` and `askopenfilename`.